# Software background building tools

Tags: commandline-build-tool

I develop a cross-platform project (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X) and use CMAKE, some python and platform-dependent scripts (sh, bat) for construction.

Nevertheless I find the process of construction before release rather boring and annoying. Switching between computers, typing commands, copying binaries, eeww.

Does anyone use some kind of building daemon? Something which can build project in the background by request or by reading special git/svn commit message.

Comment: Why not automate all those steps with Python?  Or Rake?  I used to handle very complex multi-platform builds with gnu make... if I couldn't build and install it on every supported platform with "make install" I considered it broken.

Answer (score 5):

You need to setup a [continuous integration environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). There are a number of product out there, both commercial and opensource that will do exactly what you are asking.

Basically they will sit there an poll your source control, and when it see changes you can configure it to run scripts, which could be build or make or anything you want really. Most have tools for reporting back the results, via a webpage, email, etc.

Comment: I recommend using Jenkins as your continuous integration server.

Answer (score 0):

Automate it all with a Python-based build tool.  I used to handle very complex multi-platform builds with gnu make... if I couldn't build and install it on every supported platform with "make install" I considered it broken.